# Disable / remove "Choose privacy settings for you device"

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM scale set based on a Microsoft Windows 10 pro image.

Then I login the first time Im greeted with a "Choose privacy settings for you device"

[image: Choose privacy settings for you device]

I'm pretty sure I can turn it off via a regedit option. But I simplicity can not figure out which. Does anyone know how I avoid that screen image when I log on for the first time?

Comment: The link details the **DisablePrivacyExperience** - "Don't launch privacy settings experience on user logon": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-privacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating these four reg keys, which are then executed using a custom script extension:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" -Name "PrivacyConsentStatus" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force 
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" -Name "SkipMachineOOBE" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force 
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" -Name "ProtectYourPC" -Value 3 -PropertyType DWORD -Force 
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" -Name "SkipUserOOBE" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it from Local Group Policy Editor.

1. Open local group policy editor
2. In the left pane of Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to the location below.
   Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OOBE
3. In the right pane of OOBE, double click/tap on the Don't launch privacy
   settings experience on user logon policy to edit it.To Disable Privacy Settings
   Experience at Sign-in, Select Enabled, click/tap on OK, and apply.

[image]